# Le futur du passé

Tags: temps-grammatical, origine-ou-raison

Je viens d'apprendre que ce temps existe et qu'il s'apparente au [conditionnel](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel) présent. Cependant je n'ai pas trouvé grand chose à son sujet pour en comprendre son utilité et son origine... Quelqu'un pourrait m'en dire plus ?

Comment: Cet emploi me semble très bien documenté dans la section 'expression du passé' du lien wiki que tu cites. Quel point ne te semble pas clair ?

Comment: 'expression du futur' tu veux dire ? et bien je ne comprend pas pourquoi on dit que le conditionnel présent est calqué sur le futur du passé qui m'était inconnu jusqu'à présent,  de même que le conditionnel passé (1ere forme) est calqué sur le futur antérieur du passé, encore plus étrange..

Comment: Oui, justement, je disais que ce passage (*les formes du conditionnel*) un peu obscur à propos du futur du passé est explicité dans le paragraphe *l'expression du futur* (oui désolé j'ai écrit *expression du passé* par erreur dans mon premier commentaire). En tout cas j'étais dans le même doute que toi à le lecture de ta question puis en consultant le premier § en question, mais ça m'a semblé nettement plus clair avec les exemples et explications. Pas que je veuille clore le débat bien sur, mais il me semble qu'on a déjà de bons éléments.

Comment: Si cet emploi te semble étrange, comment exprimerais-tu leur exemple (*« Jacques annonça que, dès qu'il ne pleuvrait plus, il irait chercher des champignons. »*) sans le conditionnel, tout en préservant la concordance des temps ? J'ai le sentiment que ça fait partie de ces règles que tout locuteur habitué du français applique "à l'oreille" ou à l'intuition, sans connaître la règle sous-jacente ou même réaliser que c'est du conditionnel présent.

Comment: Ce n'est pas vraiment cela qui me dérange mais le fait que l'on dise que le conditionnel présent/passé soient copiés sur le futur du passé/-antérieur du passé, qui pour moi ne sont pas des temps à prorement parlé.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je trouve cet article de wikipedia pas très clair. Et je soupçonne que ce flou vient du fait que les évolutions de la linguistique sont plus ou moins bien acceptées ou digérées. Il y a une longue tradition en France (raisons historiques) de considérer le conditionnel comme un mode et pas comme un temps. Mais depuis quelques décennies la grande majorité des linguistes estiment qu'il faut le considérer comme un temps.

Ce temps conditionnel peut exprimer différentes valeurs :

- un irréel (dans le présent ou dans le passé) :

  > Si j'en avais l'occasion je **ferais** le tour du monde.
- un souhait

  > **Pourriez**-vous me dire l'heure, s'il vous plaît ?
- un futur dans le passé, c'est à dire qu'il indique la postériorité d'une action par rapport à une autre :

  > Je savais qu'il **viendrait** aujourd'hui.

Ces quelques remarques sont très grossières et rapides, un linguiste grammairien (ce que je ne suis pas) pourrait en dire beaucoup plus.

---

J'ai cherché de quoi étayer mon explication avec quelque chose de simple. Mon édition du *Bon Usage* (1975) signale la polémique en disant que désormais le conditionnel est considéré comme un temps (mais par ailleurs parle du « mode conditionnel » Ma *Grammaire du français contemporain* (Larousse, 1964) met sans ambages le conditionnel dans les temps de l'indicatif. Mais aucun ne fait dans la simplicité.
Su internet on trouve tout et n'importe quoi. Le plus clair que j'ai trouvé c'est encore *[Bescherelle](http://www.bescherelle.com/regles.php)* dont je n'ai pas d'édition papier, et que je vous livre :

> **Le conditionnel**
>   Mode à part entière ou temps de l’indicatif ?    • La tradition
>   grammaticale fait du conditionnel un mode à part entière. Cela
>   signifie qu’elle met en valeur les emplois dans lesquels le
>   conditionnel exprime la conséquence d’une condition.
>
> > Si les vacances étaient plus longues, nous resterions une semaine de plus.
>
> • Toutefois, le conditionnel a aussi une valeur temporelle. Il sert à
>   exprimer le futur à partir du passé.
>
> > Mes parents avaient alors décidé que nous resterions une semaine de plus.
>
> • Le conditionnel est ainsi le temps complémentaire du futur > simple, qui exprime, lui, le futur à partir du présent.
>
> Le conditionnel, en conséquence, n’est pas un mode particulier, mais
>   un temps de l’indicatif.
>
> Néanmoins, il n’a pas paru souhaitable de bouleverser la présentation
>   traditionnelle, et les tableaux de conjugaison de Bescherelle isolent
>   un « mode » conditionnel.

Cette dernière phrase fait rêver ! Ou du moins **me** fait rêver quand je sais que « *le Bescherelle* » est très utilisé par les élèves des écoles et des collèges et je ne suis pas sûre cette façon de voir soit d'une clarté pédagogique à tout épreuve. Mais je m'éloigne là du français et rentre de plain pied dans la polémique.

Comment: Moi je le trouvais quand même pas si mal au départ cet article de wikipedia. Mais ton analyse est bien plus claire et plus complète (+1).

Comment: très intéressant tout cela :) merci bien !

Answer (score 1):

En fait, on ne parle pas ici d'un **temps distinct**.

C'est le [conditionnel](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/regle/conjugaison/futur_simple_indicatif.html) qu'on emploie lorsque l'action survient dans le passé.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas ce que tu cherches à défendre ou à expliquer.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez, le futur du passé n'est pas un temps distinct. Il est un emploi particulier de conditionnel (présent ou passé). On l'utilise seulement pour respecter la concordance des temps. 
On le trouve dans une proposition subordonnée qui dépend d'un verbe principal au passé.
Après tout je ne peux pas m'imaginer comment on peut comparer un temps à une mode. Peut etre vous pouvez?

Comment: @LucianSava Exact. Je ne vois pas où est le problème dans le fait d'apporter ce genre de grosses précisions quand même. https://www.assistancescolaire.com/eleve/6e/francais/lexique/F-futur-du-passe-fc_f10