# Contacter quelqu'un dans le futur

Tags: conjugaison, futur, discours-indirect

La phrase "Je lui ai dit que tu le contacteras" me semble incorrecte ainsi que la phrase "Je lui ai dit que tu le contacterais". Je veux dire "Je lui ai dit que tu prendras contact avec lui".

Comment: Pourquoi serait-ce incorrect ?

Comment: Une référence : https://www.ccdmd.qc.ca/media/con_tps_ind_10Concordance.pdf

Comment: Peut-être j’ai tort, mais il me semble que votre question ne concerne pas seulement le choix de temps entre le conditionnel ou le futur de «contacter», mais aussi, plus profondément, si cet emploi transitif  de ce verbe (quel que soit le temps) pour dire «prendre contact» est «correct» (c-à-d «pas à déconseiller»). Si c’est le cas, [voilà une référence qui s’en adresse.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/contacter) cc: @Toto

Answer (score 6):

Les règles traditionnelles<sup>1</sup> de concordance des temps ne sont pas respectées dans la première phrase :

> Je lui ai dit que tu le contacte**ras**.

Quand la proposition principale est au passé composé, la proposition subordonnée décrivant un fait postérieur est normalement au conditionnel ([futur du passé](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9430/le-futur-du-pass%C3%A9)). La deuxième phrase respecte cette règle :

> Je lui ai dit que tu le contacte**rais**.

Cependant, le futur simple est aussi possible. Il situe la subordonnée dans le futur du présent (narrateur) et insiste sur le fait qu'elle décrit un fait certain (mode indicatif), comme dans cette citation :

> Je lui ai dit que je lui donne**rai** samedi les 500 francs lui revenant

*Paul Léautaud* Journal Particulier, 1935

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Règles qui n'en sont pas vraiment. Voir :</sub>
<sub>- [La « concordance des temps revisitée », ou de la « concordance » à la « convergence »](http://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_2003_num_138_1_6485). Laurence Rosier, Marc Wilmet</sub>
<sub>- [Les discordances de la concordance](http://www.necplus.eu/abstract_S0458726X13191049) Anne-Rosine Delbart</sub>

Comment: Je trouve étrange de dire que «les règles [...] ne sont pas respectées». Est-ce que les règles traditionnelles n'indiquent pas un cas où le message survient **entre** le fait relaté _(dire à un tiers qu'on le contactera)_ et l'accomplissement de la subordonnée _(le contact se fait)_. «—Je lui ai dit que sa maison ne **supportera** pas le souffle du loup qui rôde dans les environs, mais il s'est entêté à utiliser de la paille! déclara le voisin du premier petit cochon à son cousin en visite, en lui montrant du doigt la fragile demeure.»

Comment: @Feelew C'est un abus de langage car il n'existe pas vraiment en français de « règles » de concordance des temps. C'est plutôt une « tradition » ou une ensemble de recommandations basées sur l'observation. C'est pour ça que j'ai écrit « règles traditionnelles ». C'est bien le sens qui dicte en dernier lieu le temps à utiliser dans la subordonnée et pas exclusivement le temps de la principale. C'est curieux, mais j'ai commencé toutes mes phrases par « c'est » dans ce commentaire ;-)

Answer (score 0):

C'est surtout que "tu le contacteras introduit une note de certitude, tandis que "tu le contacterais", au conditionel donc, est plus vague - the other person might or might not contact them.