# savais-tu que + imparfait ou présent de l'indicatif

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées, concordance-des-temps

Je voudrais savoir laquelle de ces deux phrases est correcte et pourquoi?

> Savais-tu qu'il y avait plusieurs parcs dans cette ville ? (l'accord avec savais-tu)
>
> Savais-tu qu'il y a un parc dans cette ville ?

Il y a des parcs dans une ville, donc je demande à un ami si il est au courant.

**MAJ suite à la réponse de @jcm69**

J'ai posé cette question car je sais qu'on ne peut pas dire par exemple

```
Il m'a dit qu'il fera ça plus tard (ou demain ou l'année prochaine ...etc)
```

Et qu'il faut plutôt dire

```
Il m'a dit qu'il ferait ça plus tard (ou demain ou l'année prochaine ...etc)
```

J'en ai déduit alors que pour toute phrase sous la forme `sujet1 + verbe1 + QUE + sujet2 + verbe2`, le temps du `verbe2` doit s'accorder avec le temps du `verbe1`, est-ce que c'est grammaticalement correct? (la question générale)

Comment: On pourrait faire la même réponse que pour [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25524/358) en transposant les noms des temps.

Comment: Ca voudrait dire que mes deux phrases sont grammaticalement correctes mais le sens diffère? @Laure

Comment: Pour moi elles le sont, un puriste pourrait objecter je suppose.

Comment: Pour moi la première peut avoir deux sens (*"il y a effectivement un parc"* et *"il y avait un parc par le passé"*).

Comment: [Certains](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25526/1514), et [non des moindres](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25618/savais-tu-que-imparfait-ou-pr%c3%a9sent-de-lindicatif/25619#comment52663_25996) disent que les règles n'en sont pas vraiment, mais pour ceux qui voudraient les apprendre, [**les règles sont décrites ici**](https://www.cap-concours.fr/sanitaire-et-social/concours-paramedicaux/reviser/maitriser-la-concordance-des-temps-cc_fra_20).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour moi, la 1ère phrase ressemble à du plus que parfait. Le passé dans le passé.   On pourrait donc comprendre (puisque c'est passé) qu'il y avait plusieurs parcs mais que maintenant ce n'est plus le cas... ou pas ! i.e. que c'est toujours la cas !  Les parcs sont toujours là !
Un plus que parfait plus traditionnel serait:

> Savais-tu il y avait eu plusieurs parcs...

C'est une histoire de concordance de temps pas d'accord. Vous pourriez dire :

> Savais-tu qu'il y a plusieurs parcs dans cette ville ?

qui lève l’ambiguïté.
Vous pourriez dire aussi :

> Savais-tu qu'il y aura bientôt plusieurs parcs, ils sont en
>   construction.

Mais peut-être ai-je mal compris votre question.
La remarque de Simon Déchamps est pertinente et je doute un peu.

Comment: Je crois qu'il demande si une des deux phrases est incorrecte, et il me semble bien que même si la première phrase est grammaticalement autorisée, elle est "fausse" au sens où elle veut dire autre chose... peut-être. **C'est une histoire de concordance des temps**, je suis bien d'accord. Mais voilà, il faudrait répondre précisément à la question de concordance des temps.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks exactement :) !  et je cherche la règle grammaticale pour que je ne me trompe plus...

Comment: @jcm69 j'ai mis à jour ma question, cependant votre réponse est intéressante mais qui me laisse encore plus confus :D vis-à-vis de la règle grammaticale

Comment: À propos de la concordance des temps, entre autres de ses limitations possibles: [une discussion et quelques liens](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25524/contacter-quelquun-dans-le-futur/25526#25526). _Le Bon usage_ cite d'entrée de jeu Brunot dans sa rubrique sur la concordance: «Ce n'est pas le temps principal qui amène le temps de la subordonnée, c'est le sens. Le chapitre de la concordance des temps se résume en une ligne: il n'y en a pas.» La concordance s'applique aussi le plus souvent pour déterminer les temps du subjonctif, pas de l'indicatif entre eux.

Comment: Suite à votre mise à jour (désolé pour le délais). Vos 2 phrases sont correctes. Simplement, dans la 1ère, vous faites entièrement confiance à votre ami et il va le faire, c'est sûr. C'est ancré dans le futur. Dans la 2ème, il vous a juste dit qu'il le ferait demain. On verra bien. C'est ce qu'il vous a dit. C'est tout. C'est donc un conditionnel. Ça va mieux ? :)

Comment: @Feelew : il n'y en a pas... ou elle est souple et dirigée par le sens. N'ai-je pas fourni une phrase avec une subordonnée au futur ? Je voulais surtout pointer pour smarber la différence entre... "concordance de temps" (je ne sais pas comment dire du coup) et un accord. Merci pour votre éclairage ;)

Comment: @jcm69 J'imagine que _concordance des temps_ pourrait en effet être l'expression qui convient. Et je perçois bien maintenant que vous n'avez jamais mentionné **les règles de la concordance des temps**, lesquelles sont je crois à prendre avec un grain de sel, le nombre de cas et situations possibles dépassant de loin ce qu'il est facile de synthétiser en quelques règles. J'ai sans doute réagi trop vivement et m'en excuse.

Comment: @Feelew Pas grave.

Answer (score -1):

"Savais-tu qu'il y avait plusieurs parcs dans cette ville ?"
voudrait dire que les parcs ne sont plus présents dans la ville.

Comment: Il se pourrait aussi que les personnes ne soient plus dans la ville en question et discutent de leurs séjours respectifs au passé. L'imparfait n'implique pas l'absence plus tard, simplement la présence en un moment du passé. Sinon, pourquoi spécifierait-on, le cas échéant: «Il y avait des parcs dans cette ville à l'époque, quoique la plupart sont aujourd'hui disparus.»?

Comment: Réponse bien trop péremptoire à mon avis. L'utilisation de l'imparfait par concordance des temps avec un autre imparfait, pour décrire une situation présente, est une vraie problématique. *"Je ne savais pas que tu étais informaticien !"* ; *"Je me doutais bien que tu étais un salaud"*.