# Why the past conditional "J’aurais mis"?

Tags: temps-grammatical, conditionnel

"Sometimes you just have to grin and bear it and persevere for what seems like an eternity before your efforts pay dividends. **J’aurais mis** dix ans à m'en rendre compte, mais ça en valait la peine au final."

If I guess from context, this past conditional seems to mean either of the following. Is this past conditional usage frequently heard?

"**J’ai peut-être mis** dix ans à m'en rendre compte, mais ça en valait la peine au final."

"**D’accord, j’ai mis** dix ans à m'en rendre compte, mais ça en valait la peine au final."

"**J’ai mis** dix ans à m'en rendre compte, **certes**, mais ça en valait la peine au final."

"**J’ai beau avoir mis** dix ans à m'en rendre compte, ça en valait la peine au final."

Comment: Attention, tu vas te faire taper sur les doigts par l'Académie ;-) http://www.academie-francaise.fr/au-final

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, tiens, j'ai appris un truc, merci! :)

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9430/le-futur-du-pass%c3%a9

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the spelling "J'aurai", no s in the end.

Here, the tense and mode are different from what you suppose them to be. You are dealing in fact with the "futur antérieur de l'indicatif"; it is used here to express a nuance ;

- récapitulation, bilan, ironie, indignation, surprise, regret, ironie

[encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futur_ant%C3%A9rieur_en_fran%C3%A7ais), [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=futur+ant%C3%A9rieur&btn_chercher=CHERCHER&id=4129)

This turn is used frequently; none of the four sentences are proper as  possible equivalent; here is a possible rephrasing;

- Ça m'a pris malheureusement dix ans pour m'en rendre compte, mais ça en vaut la peine.

It seems that regret on the ground of the long time needed is the main idea.

Comment: It is a conditional, not a futur antérieur. Futur antérieur would not be `J'aurais mis` but `J'aurai mis`...

Comment: @Steph I think you are not right; I didn't remove the s when I made the correction so as to keep the question consistent, and will make that precise now (I thought there would be no problem). If it were a conditionnal we'd have to deduce that the person did not spend ten years; however it is is clear from the four sentences that follow that the ten years were spent. In case you interpret my "you are dealing with" as applying to the tense and mood actually used, that's not correct: it means "you are dealing with a problem that calls for the "futur antérieur"".

Comment: I think j'aurais is incorrect here, too, there's no condition in the context. It would be correct with a phrase like this: "J’aurais mis dix ans à m'en rendre compte, si ça avait pu en valoir la peine alors" (there's a condition), but since it's clearly future, there's no s.

Comment: @Simon and @LPH : It seems you both did not read my answer... It is not a conditional to express a condition but to express a _futur dans le passé_ (more precisely a _futur antérieur dans le passé_). Notice that the verb of the main clause is at a past tense (`valait`).

Comment: @Steph  That's the point, you are talking about modality and there seems to be no such possibility; the only thing I find in the BDL is a use for expressing indignation ("indignation" in French), but in an exclamation or an interrogation: "Le conditionnel peut aussi exprimer l'étonnement ou l'indignation dans une phrase exclamative ou interrogative. 
- Vraiment, il aurait parlé de moi!
- Gaston habiterait maintenant à Rimouski?
- Aurais-tu perdu la raison?__ What references explaining that  can you quote ?

Comment: @LPH : Well, it is not a matter of modality but a mere matter of _concordance des temps_. For modality, your first check of what can be expressed by futur antérieur _was_ the right check, since it is a futur antérieur dans le passé. Other example: `Je te dis que je viendrai quand le moment sera venu` (présent, futur, futur antérieur) when put in the past, regularly becomes `Je t'ai dit que je viendrais quand le moment serait venu` (passé composé, conditionnel, conditionnel passé). Same applies here.

Comment: @Steph According to this [source](https://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/le-futur-anterieur-de-lindicatif-niveau-b2.html), when the "future antérieur" is used by itself there is only the possibility of  modality.

Comment: @Steph - I did read your answer more than once before posting my comment, but to be honest, I don't understand it as a whole, as it mixes different things. And "Je t'ai dit que je viendrais quand le moment serait venu" is completely incorrect since there is no condition, you can't keep "quand" in this phrase if you choose conditionnel.

Comment: @SimonMourier Your assertion as to the complete incorrectness is very apparently inexact; consider this [source](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel), the example « Jacques annonça que, dès qu'il ne pleuvrait plus, il irait chercher des champignons. » that is found in it and what is said concerning this example. There is no doubt  that  "dès que", a "locution conjonctive", can be replaced   by "quand" (commutes with "quand"), another conjunction that refers to time.

Answer (score 1):

There is in French a notion of "futur dans le passé" (future in the past). This is a use of the conditional to convey something future from a past point of view.

1) It works for a simple futur:

`Je te promets que je t'aiderai` (present sentence with a future)

put in the past, it becomes:

`Je t'ai promis que je t'aiderais`. (notice the conditional)

2) It also works for more complex constructs. For the asked sentence, let's start with something easier:

`J'ai mis dix ans à m'en rendre compte, mais ça en vaut la peine.` is a sentence in present tense, with a passé composé. Its meaning is rather straightforward.

`J’aurai mis dix ans à m'en rendre compte, mais ça en vaut la peine.` is a sentence in the present tense, with a futur antérieur. It adds a nuance of "récapitulation, bilan, ironie, indignation, surprise, regret, ironie" as explained by LPH.

And finally, your sentence:

`J’aurais mis dix ans à m'en rendre compte, mais ça en valait la peine.` is the same sentence, put in the past.

Note: To be complete, though not related to the question, if you start with my first sentence, not adding the futur antérieur nuance, and put it in the past, it becomes:

`J’avais mis dix ans à m'en rendre compte, mais ça en valait la peine.` (with pluperfect)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a mistake. The proper tense that should be used here is futur antérieur, which spells "j'aurai mis". Here it is indeed spelled as a conditionnel, which is a rather common mistake, unfortunately.