# «J'ai fait ce que j'avais dit que je ferai»

Tags: grammaire, concordance-des-temps

Emmanuel Macron a [déclaré](https://twitter.com/EmmanuelMacron/status/1283022413949743105) :

> J'ai fait ce que j'avais dit que je ferai.

J'ai vu plein de commentaires mentionnant une éventuelle faute de français du président français. Il aurait peut-être dû écrire *(...) je ferais* (au conditionnel au lieu du futur). Il me semble pourtant que la phrase est juste puisqu'il parle d'une promesse et donc de quelque chose qu'il voulait faire et non d'un conditionnel.

Quelqu'un peut-il confirmer si cette phrase est grammaticalement juste ou sinon expliquer pourquoi ?

Comment: « J’ai fait » au moment où je vous parle *ce qui était écrit* dans mon programme, programme *qui disait* à cette époque *ce que **je ferai** si j’étais élu*, et donc « ce que j'avais dit que je ferai. »

Comment: @Personne On dit « ce que je **ferais** si j’étais élu ». Pas besoin de longues explications pour s’en convaincre ; si on n’a pas le courage d’ouvrir une grammaire, il suffit de comparer avec : « ce que nous **ferions** si nous étions élus ». Pour utiliser le futur, il faut tourner ça autrement ; par exemple : « ce que je ferai si je suis élu » (« ce que nous ferons si nous sommes élus »).

Comment: @Philippe-AndréLorin — Mes connaissances grammaticales sont limitées https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/personne?tab=profile à l’inverse de mon goût de la francophonie orale https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110647/discussion-between-personne-and-jlliagre

Comment: … *si on n’a pas le courage d’ouvrir une grammaire*, est pour le moins pas très idoine, je n’y ai pas trouvé la réponse pour la phrase posée,  et votre réponse est basée sur l’ajout du conditionnel et le changement du point de vue/de l’époque à laquelle parle le locuteur :
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54973761#54973761 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pas sûr qu'il écrive lui-même ses tweets mais si on met la phrase à la troisième personne du singulier ou à la première du pluriel, la phrase sonne plutôt mal...

> Il a fait ce qu'il avait dit qu'il *fera*.

> Nous avons fait ce que nous avions dit que nous *ferons*.

[image]

Viginie Despentes, *Vernon Subutex*, 2015.

Le futur simple du tweet est incorrect. On écrit:

> J'ai fait ce que j'avais dit que je **ferais**.

Il ne s'agit pas ici d'un conditionnel au sens strict (il n'y a pas de condition ou d'hypothèse) mais d'un [futur du passé.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel#L%27expression_du_futur) (voir aussi [cette question sur FSE](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9430/le-futur-du-pass%C3%A9) et cette [autre sur « Dire, ne pas dire »](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/je-pensais-que-je-viendrai) de l'Académie française).

Note: cette manière d'exprimer le futur du passé n'est pas une fantaisie récente mais un héritage du latin qui existe depuis toujours en français.

> Selon Benveniste, le conditionnel français a pour origine une périphrase latine porteuse d’une valeur de prédestination : *infinitif + habebam*. Cette périphrase a par la suite développé, en latin vulgaire, deux sens qu’elle a ultérieurement transmis aux conditionnels romans: (i) le sens de futur
> du passé observable par exemple en discours indirect, et (ii) le sens d’*irrealis-potentialis* qui a émergé dans les constructions hypothétiques. Pour Fleischman, ce second sens serait une extension du sens de futur du passé dont il serait pragmatiquement dérivé.

Source: *[L’évolution des usages du conditionnel en français](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01701157/document)*, Adeline Patard et Walter De Mulder, 2018

Comment: Sortir la parole de l’acteur de son contexte et la mettre dans l’écrit d’un observateur muet … hum … n’introduit-on pas un concept qui déforme la réalité retranscrite ?

Comment: Je trouve que la phrase à la troisième personne ne sonne pas particulièrement fausse.

Comment: Ta tolérance aux écarts avec la norme est plus grande que la mienne. Par exemple: ne sonne pas particulièrement **faux** ;-)

Comment: "… mais d'un futur du passé. " — bigre, depuis quand enseigne-t-on cette utilisation du conditionnel ? apparemment depuis longtemps https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avais+dit+que+je+ferai%2C+avais+dit+que+je+ferais&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true … il ne faut vraiment pas aimer la francophonie pour imposer un tel mic-mac dans les temps sous prétexte de bien l’écrire. Mélanger le temps, n’est-ce pas un signe précoce de maladie neurodégénérative des académiciens ?

Comment: @Personne Ce n'est pas que les grammaires enseignent une utilisation incongrue du subjonctif, c'est au contraire que les grammaires traditionnelles ne rendent pas compte de l'usage majoritaire du subjonctif. Certains linguistes préféreraient d'ailleurs le classifier comme un temps de l'indicatif. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel#Mode_ou_temps_.3F

Comment: *Futur catégorique* et *futur hypothétique* sont clairs et pourquoi pas *suppositif*. ils sont soutenus pas la logique du bon sens … l’amalgame retenu, me rappelle les premiers amalgames dentaires, un mélange toxique à long terme

Comment: @Personne Les langues ont (parfois) des logiques que la logique ne connaît pas...

Comment: … pas *Les langues …*, cela concerne uniquement la ‘logique’ de ceux qui s’en servent comme outils de pouvoir (Académie française = émanation royale de Louis XIII), ‘logique’ centré sur leurs seuls profits/ego :-) , c’est cela qui chagrine et tavèle *Les langues …*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110647/discussion-between-personne-and-jlliagre).

Answer (score 2):

J'aurais tendance à dire que la faute vient du fait qu'on utilise le conditionnel pour exprimer un futur dans le passé.

Comme la principale est au passé composé, on utilise le conditionnel.

Par exemple on [dira](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/regle/conjugaison/futur_simple_indicatif.html) :

> - Il dit (présent) qu'il viendra (futur) avec nous.
> - Il a déclaré (passé) qu'il viendrait (conditionnel) avec nous.

Autrement, la phrase n'est effectivement pas très jolie, peut-être plutôt :

> J'ai fait ce que j'avais prévu de faire.

Answer (score 0):

Si on considère que sur Twitter les messages écrits sont souvent une sorte transcription de messages oraux, il est probable que l'orthographe "... ce que je *ferai*" reflète une prononciation que je qualifierais de "parisienne" du conditionnel. En effet, dans ce type de prononciation, il n'y a (presque) pas de différence entre la prononciation du futur (je *ferai*) et celle du conditionnel (je *ferais*).

Comment: Pour confirmer mon point de vue. Entendu ce midi dans l'émission du Jeu des 1000 Euros sur France Inter. L'animateur demande aux candidats quand est-ce que "je ferais" (prononcé avec un ê ouvert) prend ou non un "s" final. Réponse attendue, ça prend un "s" quand c'est un conditionnel, pas de "s" si c'est un futur ! Absurde, si on prononce en français standard je ferai (é) ou je ferais (ê), il n'y a pas lieu de (se) poser la question. Au fait, peut-on poster de la phonétique dans ses commentaires sur ce site ?